# Chrome APIs for packaged apps - need access to bookmarks, cookies, history, etc

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am the author of a Firefox extension named FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup Extension) and would like to port it to Chrome.  Before I get too far into it, I have a few questions.

FEBE relies heavily on low-level APIs (XPCOM) that allow unfettered access to manipulate most browser components - extensions, cookies, bookmarks, user login/passwords, history, etc. I've noticed so far that `chrome.bookmarks`, `chrome.cookies`, and `chrome.history` seem to be only available to extensions, and `chrome.fileSystem` only to apps.  Because of this, I envision the chrome counterpart of FEBE to be a hybrid extension/packaged app that communicates through `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.  Since chrome bookmarks are stored as JSON files and cookies, history and others are stored as SQL files, I suppose I could also manage them with my own javascript code and release it as an app only.  Is this allowed?  By this I mean do developers have to use chrome apis exclusively or can they write their own.

I could also probably repackage a user's extensions into crx files, but does chrome allow the installation of local crx files (i.e., restoring backed up extensions from a local drive)?

Comment: You would need to ask the user to open the directory containing their chrome profile using chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry if you went app-only. (but aren't the cookies/bookmarks encrypted there anyway?)

Comment: I does appear there is some encrypted data at least in the Cookies file.  But for a backup/restore process I would only need to read/write the data, not parse it.  Does one have to use chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry even if the data is located in a static, known location?  The average user would not even know where the chrome profile is located.

Comment: That's right, apps only get access to user directory after user manually selects it. There is no other way to get access through chrome apps. It's a security feature.